# Generating Http 301 Response Message

Tags: java, webserver, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to create a little web server and have be able to generate Http response messages 200, 301, and 404.

I am able to get 200 and 404 to work, but I am having problems with 301.

When I try to access a page that has "permanently moved" my browser doesn't get redirected and I get a java.lang.NullPointerException from java.

The way I have it determine if the code should be a 301 is it checks a list of strings for the file the client is trying to access, and if the original file they're trying to access has been moved, it will be in the list, along with it's new name/location. So if the original file is "index5.html" and it's been moved to "index.html" then they will be in an array and "index5.html" will be in an index 1 before "index.html"

I'm also just testing this on my own machine so I'm using localhost for the URL and using port 9012.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public final class HttpRequest implements Runnable {
    final static String CarrLine = "\r\n";
    Socket clientSocket;

    // A list of files that have been moved.
    // Even indexes (0, 2, 4, ...) are the original file names.
    // Odd indexes (1, 3, 5, ...) are where the files of previous indexes moved to.
    static String movedFiles[] = {"index5.html", "index.html", "page.html", "homepage.html"};

    // This sets the Httprequest object socket equal to
    // the socket the client comes in through
    public HttpRequest(Socket socket) throws Exception {
        this.clientSocket = socket;
    }

    // Here we define a new method that overwrites the
    // previous method in the Runnables class. This is done
    // so that when an Http request is attempted, and
    // something goes wrong, our whole web server will
    // not fail and crash.
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {

            // This is where the method to actually start the Http request starts.
            requestProcessing();

        } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.print(ex); }
    } 


    // This is our main processing method to take in out Http request
    // and spit out a reponse header along with the requested data,
    // if there is any.
    void requestProcessing() throws Exception {
        Boolean fileExists = false;

        String CarrLine = "\r\n";
        String statusCode = null;
        String responseHeader = "HTTP/1.1 ";
        String fileName, line = null;
        String clientSentence = null;

        ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileInputStream requestedFileStream = null;
        File requestedFile;

        // Starts input from client and establishes filters
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        // Starts output stream for output to client through socket
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        /*
        // Reads in GET from client BufferedReader
        while ( (line = inFromClient.readLine()) != null){
            records.add(line);
            break;
        }*/
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

        // Parses and stores file name the client wants in a string
        fileName = parseGET(clientSentence);


        if (!existingFile(fileName)){

            // Here is where the 301 response message is generated and
            // retrieve the correct filename.
            if (hasMoved(fileName) != -1){
                statusCode = "301";
                responseHeader = responseHeader + statusCode + " Moved Permanently\n";
                responseHeader = responseHeader + "Location: localhost:9012/" 
                        + movedFiles[hasMoved(fileName)] + CarrLine;

            }

            // This generates the response header for the client
            // if the file the client is looking for is not there (404).
            else {
                statusCode = "404";
                responseHeader = responseHeader + statusCode + " Not Found: \n";
                responseHeader = responseHeader + "Content-Type: text/html" + CarrLine;
            }

        }

        // This generates the 200 status code response header
        // to send to the client saying the file was found.
        if (existingFile(fileName)) {
            statusCode = "200";
            responseHeader = responseHeader + statusCode + " OK: \n";
            responseHeader = responseHeader + "Content-Type: " + fileType(fileName) + CarrLine;
            requestedFileStream = openFileStream(fileName);
        }

        // Outputs the response message to the client through a data stream
        outToClient.writeBytes(responseHeader);
        outToClient.writeBytes(CarrLine);

        // If the file the client is requesting exists,
        // begin writing file out to client.
        if (existingFile(fileName)){
            fileWriteOut(requestedFileStream, outToClient);
            requestedFileStream.close();
        }

        else if(hasMoved(fileName) != -1){
            outToClient.writeBytes("File Moved");
        }

        // If the file the client is requesting does not exist,
        // return a 404 message.
        else {
            outToClient.writeBytes("404: File not found!");
        }

        // Closes all open streams and sockets to the client.
        inFromClient.close();
        outToClient.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }

    // This parses the GET line from the client to get the filename the client is requesting
    String parseGET(String clientString){

        String temp[] = clientString.split(" /");
        temp = temp[1].split(" ");
        return temp[0];
    }

    // This is used to find the file the client is requesting.
    // It will return null if no file was found/opened.
    FileInputStream openFileStream(String file){
        FileInputStream fileStream = null;

        // Opening the file stream is in a try catch statment so that
        // incase there was no file, the program doesn't crash
        // and it'll alert the user on the console.
        try {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
            }

        return fileStream;
    }

    // Determines the file type that is being sent to the client
    // and returns the appropriate string
    String fileType(String clientRequestFile){

        // If the file ends in .html or .htm, it will return "text/html"
        // so that it can be added to the response message.
        if (clientRequestFile.endsWith(".html") || clientRequestFile.endsWith(".htm")){
            return "text/html";
        }

        // If the file ends in .jpg, it will return "text/jpeg"
        // so that it can be added to the response message.
        if (clientRequestFile.endsWith(".jpg")){
            return "text/jpg";
        }

        // If the file ends in .css, it will return "text/css"
        // so that it can be added to the response message.
        if (clientRequestFile.endsWith(".css")){
            return "text/css";
        }

        // Returns this by default, if none of the above.
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    // This creates a 2k buffer and writes out
    // requested filed to the client.
    static void fileWriteOut(FileInputStream clientStream, OutputStream toClient) throws Exception{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytes = 0;

        while ((bytes = clientStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            toClient.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }

    }

    // This determines whether or not a file that
    // the client has requested exists or not.
    // Returns a Boolean value.
    static Boolean existingFile(String fileName){
        File file = new File(fileName);

        if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    // Determines if a file has been moved and if so,
    // returns the index of the NEW file. Else it
    // returns -1.
    static int hasMoved(String fileName){
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < movedFiles.length; i=i+2){
            if (movedFiles[i].equals(fileName)){
                return i+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to doing this correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

It was because I was trying to define the entire "URL" in the 301 response messages.

So it should have been:

```
responseHeader = responseHeader + "Location: /" + movedFiles[hasMoved(fileName)] + CarrLine;
```

Instead of:

```
responseHeader = responseHeader + "Location: localhost:9012/" + movedFiles[hasMoved(fileName)] + CarrLine;
```